# upload file(image) using js and webservice C#

Tags: javascript, web-services

So far I found something related to what I am looking for, but I'm not sure if this is what I need: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479273/javascript-sendfile-binary-data-to-web-service)

How do I convert the file to byte in js and send it to webservices to upload to server.

Example:

JS:

```
<script>
    webService.UploadFile(Myfilebytes,suc,fail);
</script>
```

C#:

```
[Web Method]
public string UploadFile(byte[] Myfilebytes)
{
     //UPloading script
    return "OK";
}
```

Comment: I can't find how to change my file into byte.Thank yOu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't convert the file to a byte array; it already is one. Your browser manages the responsibility of formatting the data to send to a web service. Typically this is achieved through a POST on a form with an `input` of type `file`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="UploadFile" method="post">
    <input id="image" type="file" />
</form>
```

Using a `WebMethod` on the C# side is not possible, however, as POST variables are received through the request information, of which a `WebMethod` does not provide. You can create a web handler and use the `ProcessRequest` method to receive this info, but this is not the only way.

Comment: thanks, I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431365/filereader-readasbinarystring-to-upload-files/14509092#14509092 , but I can't get it wokk. How can I implement it?