# JS - html5 file reader API - get file as binary string and send it via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, binary

i'm trying getting binary string of the files but as i can see i'm unable actually, why readAsDataUrl works while readAsBinaryString won't ?

I putted my code in jsbin any help appriciated thanks.

[updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odemuv/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

```
img.src = e.target.result;
```

Dude, the "src" attribute of an image is a URL, not a string where every character is an int between 0 and 255 !!

You have to use ReadAsArrayBuffer() instead, and then the canvas API to render the ArrayBuffer you have into the context of a canvas.

**Edit:**
If you don't want to show it in an image, but just to Ajax it to your server, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613360/does-filereader-readasbinarystring-return-binary-or-an-ascii-based-character-set) is a solution !

Comment: hey buddy, i would like only to get binary string of the file and send it via ajax, how can i do that? :(