# Send file to OneDrive API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, onedrive

I have some problems uploading files to the "OneDrive Api".

I get the URL to upload de file:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: folderUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    success: {.....}
});
```

And with it i get the "upload url". THen i read and upload the file that the user select (I need fragment the file):

```
var fileInput = $("#file");
var fileList = fileInput[0].files;
var file = fileList[0];
content_length = file.size;
inicio = 0;
var blob = file.slice(inicio, content_length);

fileReader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var result = evt.target.result;

        $.ajax({
            method: "PUT",
            url: uploadUrl,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                'Content-Range': "bytes " + inicio + "-" + ((inicio + evt.target.result.length)-1) + "/" + content_length,
            },
            data: result,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("subió");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("falló");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null));
            }
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }
};

fileReader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

When i upload text files with content like

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" (without special characters 'ñ', 'á',
>   etc...)

It work.

But, when upload files with especial characters ("ñ", "á", "¿"....) show the error:

```
"code":"invalidRequest","message":"**Declared fragment length does not match the provided number of bytes**"
```

With files like ".doc", ".zip" and more too.

[EDIT]: I noticed the "á" change for "Ã¡" (For example).

I need help :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an encoding issue, and my guess is the culprit is `readAsBinaryString`. Try switching to `readAsArrayBuffer` and see if that helps.

[This answer goes into a lot more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431365/filereader-readasbinarystring-to-upload-files#answer-17512132)